# Is the sentence “Sie betonte jedoch, die Geldpolitik folge keinem vorgegebenem Kurs” correct?

Tags: grammar, dative, adjective-ending, indefinite-pronoun

I came across this sentence in *Der Spiegel*:

> Sie betonte jedoch, die Geldpolitik folge keinem vorgegebenem Kurs.

Should not the sentence read *vorgegebene**n** Kurs*?

Comment: @Em1 Sorry to ask you about this, but how did you place the quoted sentence against yellowish background?

Comment: "> Sie betonte jedoch..." see formatting option: "blockquote"

Comment: Just click "edit" and take a look at what the "code" looks like. Or use the "help" button while editing. Or believe Iris. ;)

Comment: I vote to believe Iris. Sounds safest xD

Comment: @chirlu: The two questions you saw as other-language duplicates are not. In this case, we don’t have two adjectives but rather an adjective and a pseudo-article (for want of a better word). This invalidates the answers given to the other question.

Comment: @Jan: Well, you can argue that they are different. However, the end result (fluctuant use of *-en* or *-em* for the adjective in second position) is the same; a few Google searches as evidence: ["keinem anderem"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22keinem+anderem%22), ["keinem großem"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22keinem+gro%C3%9Ferem%22), ["keinem besonderem"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22keinem+besonderem%22).

Comment: @chirlu The end result is not the same. The other post argues that the same ending on both **adjectives** is possible and correct, as is mixed declination. So I can have *Weißwürscht mit echtem bayerische**m** Senf* or *Weißwürscht mit echtem bayerische**n** Senf*. With *kein*, however, the other option is not possible, so linking the two questions together does more harm than good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would indeed agree that it should read

> ... keine**m** vorgegebene**n** Kurs

This goes along the lines of

> ... steht in keinem vernünftigen Verhältnis
>   ... aus keinem offensichtlichen Grund

Answer (score 7):

[*Kein* is an indefinite pronoun](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-Indef/Pron-kein3.html) that functions as an article would. And it has almost the same effects on adjectives following it as articles have.

When standing alone, adjectives use the strong inflection:

> - Vorgegebene**r** Kurs
> - Vorgegebene**n** Kurses
> - Vorgegebene**m** Kurs
> - Vorgegebene**n** Kurs

When preceeded by a definite article, weak inflection is used:

> - der vorgegebene Kurs
> - des vorgegebene**n** Kurses
> - dem vorgegebene**n** Kurs
> - den vorgegebene**n** Kurs

With indefinite pronouns and articles, a [mixed inflection](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adjektiv/Deklinationstyp/Gemischt.html) is used which marks the nominative on the adjective and all other cases on the pronoun article:

> - kein vorgegebene**r** Kurs
> - keines vorgegebene**n** Kurses
> - keinem vorgegebene**n** Kurs
> - keinen vorgegebene**n** Kurs

Therefore, the only correct way to write it would have been:

> Sie betonte jedoch, die Geldpolitik folge keinem vorgegebene**n** Kurs.